# Map Linux drives to Windows 7 for media streaming over the internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn

I'm trying to map a Linux network drive to my Windows 7 laptop, however this laptop is not on LAN. At home, I simply use Samba, but this obviously won't work over the internet.

I'm trying to avoid VPN, so if there are other solutions, I would like to know about them. The reason I ask is because my university does this as well. We can simply map folders to our computers without VPN connections. I'm not sure what they are running as servers.

The main reason is because I want to be able to access my files stored on my home server wherever I go. They are located in the `/home/ folder` (videos, music and pictures folder). I'm trying to keep my websites and media separate from each other.

I wouldn't mind accessing them from a web interface either, but I would like to keep the directory structure intact. I remember having an app like that come with Winamp and running it on my windows pc (As the server). Unfortunately it doesn't work for Linux.

Any ideas on what I could use? Would XBMC be able to help me out with this?

I did do some researching but I couldn't find any concrete answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SMB over the internet. Samba/SMB/CIFS is an [application layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) protocol, which sits on top of [transport layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer) protocols such as TCP. That's probably what your university is using.

Instead of using a NetBIOS name such as `\\myservername\` to connect, you would just use `\\ipaddr\` or `\\example.com\`

e.g. at a Windows command prompt, type `net use \\192.168.1.100\myshare\mysubfolder` to connect to the folder `mysubfolder` on the share `myshare` on the computer at 192.168.1.100.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best media server you can get is [Serviio](http://www.serviio.org/download) .  I wouldn't even bother with network shares myself, for this kind of thing.   Then, you can use VLC Media player to play the media streams from a Mac or a PC.